# How to prove an expression is positive

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, approximation

I wanted to know if there are some standard methods to proving an algebraic expression is positive.

For example, how could I prove that $\dfrac{9\pi^2}{16}-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}>0$ without using approximations of $\pi$ or $\sqrt{2}$.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{9\pi^2}{16} \gt \frac{\sqrt2}{2}$$
$$\pi^2 \gt \frac{8\sqrt2}{9}$$
We know that $\pi \gt 8/9$ and that $\pi \gt \sqrt2$, so $\pi^2 \gt \frac{8\sqrt2}{9}$